# OSHI: Get HWDiskStore for a given path

Tags: java, jna, disk, oshi

I am using OSHI https://github.com/oshi/oshi to monitor the hardware.

There is a method

```
HWDiskStore[] getDisks();
```

https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/master/oshi-core/src/main/java/oshi/hardware/Disks.java
to get the list of all hard drives on the machine.

Is it possible to get `HWDiskStore` for a particular path like

```
FileStore getFileStore(Path path)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getFileStore-java.nio.file.Path-

If no, what is a reliable way to match a `HWDiskStore` with a given path, e.g. use disk name or serial number, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

The DiskStore is a hardware object (e.g., hard drive, SSD, etc.) which is part of the machinery, while the FileStore is a software object associated with the Operating System / File System.

OSHI's `HWDiskStore` objects have a [`getPartitions()`](http://oshi.github.io/oshi/apidocs/oshi/hardware/HWDiskStore.html#getPartitions--) method, which returns an array of `HWPartition` objects. These objects have a [`getMountPoint()`](http://oshi.github.io/oshi/apidocs/oshi/hardware/HWPartition.html#getMountPoint--) method which should be a `String` corresponding to the `OSFileStore` mount point.

OSHI's `OSFileStore` objects correspond to the Java `FileStore` objects and have a [`getMount()`](http://oshi.github.io/oshi/apidocs/oshi/software/os/OSFileStore.html#getMount--) method which should directly match the `HWPartition` mount point.

This [demo class](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/master/oshi-demo/src/main/java/oshi/demo/DiskStoreForPath.java) gives an example of how this information can be correlated.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it once I will get it working: https://github.com/oshi/oshi/issues/669

Comment: (1) seems like I can determine the right partition by `pathStr.toUpperCase().startsWith(partition.getMountPoint().toUpperCase())`, where `partition` is `HWPartition` (2) whether `OSFileStore` has a method similar to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html#getUsableSpace--? (3) VERY IMPORTANT: is it possible to get `reads, readBytes, writes, writeBytes` and similar statistics per partition, not only per hard drive?

Comment: (4) `partition.getMountPoint()` returns `C:\Unknown` for disk `C:`, so (1) can be unreliable...

Comment: (2) OSFileStore does have a [`getUsableSpace()`](http://oshi.github.io/oshi/apidocs/oshi/software/os/OSFileStore.html#getUsableSpace--) method.  (3) This functionality is not in OSHI and I don't think it's possible in Windows. Even in linux [you can only get reads/writes (and sectors read/write) issued](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt) without any confirmation they completed. (4) seems like a bug, please report it at the OSHI site!

Comment: (2) just to be sure: this is the free space, right? (3) "In 2.6.25, the full statistic set is again available for partitions and disk and partition statistics are consistent again." is this true for higher versions of the kernel? Seems that `iostat -p` does the job for `3.13.0-119-generic`. (4) done

Comment: (2) Yes, free/usable space. Of note, there may be a distinction on some OS's between usable for all users and available for privileged users.  But OSHI's statistic (all users) matches the interpretation in the JDK `FileStore` class.  (3) Beyond my skillset to interpret!

Comment: (3) is it possible to implement in OSHI (i.e. per partition stats)?

Comment: OSHI focuses on cross-platform stats and in general this information isn't available across most OS's.  If you can figure out how to do it consistently you're welcome to submit your code to OSHI to improve it!